# Bootstrap 4.1: Validate form input using custom JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json, bootstrap-4

I'm writing a personal test page to be used for debugging our embedded server-side JSON RPC implementation. The page is built using Bootstrap 4.1. As part of the page, I want to be able to specify an arbitrary JSON object to send as the RPC parameters, which I should be able to enter as text into a text box input.

In an ideal world, I'd like the form to be able to validate the JSON before it is sent. I have a function which calls `JSON.parse()` on the input, and sets a custom error message in the form depending on the message given back in any encountered exception.

However, I can't seem to solve the last piece of the puzzle, which is to get Bootstrap to consider the form input as invalid and so display this error text. As far as I understand (after some experimentation and confusion), this is the way things work:

- Form inputs have validation properties specified on them, eg. `required`, min/max range, regex pattern, etc.
- Setting Bootstrap's `was-validated` class on the form causes any inputs that fail the aforementioned validation conditions to be marked appropriately, and their success/failure messages are displayed.

This is OK for relatively straightforward validation such as range and patterns, but in my case I essentially need to run *completely arbitrary* JavaScript (ie. `JSON.parse()`) to validate the input. As far as I can see, there is no ability to specify a function *per input* to call for validation.

I guess that one option would be to forego Bootstrap's validation process for this particular input and insert validation messages manually off my own back, but I'm wondering if there's a more Bootstrap-compliant way to achieve this?

Comment: JSON.parse() is a slow function that should be passed to promise or callback, to be handled asynchronously and this is why I guess you are having problem

Comment: Sync/async isn't the issue here - it wouldn't matter whether I had a fast or slow, sync or async function. My question is that I don't know how I would call *any* function in the first place in order to do this validation.